# word-wrap not working on a floating text

Tags: html, css, css-float, word-wrap

Let's say I have this.

```
<div>
<div id="lala">
lalalala
</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#lala
{
   float:left;
   word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

if the text inside `#lala` is big, it will look like this.

```
|                              |
|                              |
| lalalalalalalalalalalalalala | lalalalalala <-- these won't be show.
|                              |
|                              |
```

If I remove `float:left;` this will be the result.

```
|                              |
|                              |
| lalalalalalalalalalalalalala |
| lalalalalala                 |
|                              |
```

How can I have the second result while still using float?

Comment: Perhaps if you provide more context (what element is #lala in? what larger effect are you looking for?), a solution will be more apparent. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

give the element a fixed width so we know where to break the word:

```
#lala
{
float:left;
word-wrap:break-word;
width:?px;
}
```

The word-wrap:break-word property should only apply if the element has a visual rendering, is an inline element with explicit height/width, is absolutely positioned and/or is a block element.

Comment: I am trying to move away from fixed widths, I just feel it's not a professional way, if there's another solution it would be better, and maybe I'm wrong, but I'll use this solution now.

Comment: Use percents %, they are fluid.